# Max instructions for each core in multi-core SE mode

Tags: gem5

I am running gem5 in two-core SE mode. I want each core to simulate 1billion instructions. I understood from Gem5 mail archive that "max_inst_all_threads" does not decide number of instructions across cores.
Can anybody please suggest, how can I make sure that each core simulate a minimum number of instructions (1 billion in my case) before exiting.
Thanks
KP Arun

Comment: I would give a shot at patching gem5 to solve this, guessing won't be hard.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: Thanks for your reply, I realised that I need to patch in Simulation.py . figuring out the code :)